# How can I give (or sell?) my dwarves mugs

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

I've crafted two bins full of mugs, yet I still have dwarves having unhappy thoughts about drinking without mugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need an Inn or dining hall with a storage

First, you need to create an inn or dining Room.

In an Inn, add a chest/coffer, and suddenly it will start to gather mugs, cups, and other goblets to hand to its patrons.

In a Dining Hall, have a stockpile area that is only for [Goblet typ](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Finished_goods#Goblets)e products.